# Undefined property on JSON response

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to parse a JSON object which is from this link [api.worldweather.com](http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/weather.ashx?key=3be20163414371b55549cb84e2e47&q=durgapur%20wb&format=json)

And this is my php code:

```
<?php

$base_url = "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/weather.ashx?key=3be20163414371b55549cb84e2e47&q=" . "durgapur+wb&format=json";
$ret = file_get_contents($base_url);
$data = json_decode($ret);
$type = $data->data->current_condition->FeelsLikeC;
echo $type;

?>
```

Any Help would really would really be appreciated. Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under `current_condition`, there is still a dimension (array):

```
stdClass Object
(
    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [current_condition] => Array
                ( // index 0, this is an array
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [cloudcover] => 34
                            [FeelsLikeC] => 28
```

So you need an index 0:

```
$base_url = "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/weather.ashx?key=3be20163414371b55549cb84e2e47&q=" . "durgapur+wb&format=json";
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($base_url));
$type = $data->data->current_condition[0]->FeelsLikeC;
                                    // ^ another nesting
echo $type;
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/kYXaXO)